# How do I split an NSString based on capitalization (i.e. capital letters) in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, split, capitalization

Using Objective C, what would be the best way to split an NSString based on capitalization, e.g. `@"MyNameOfSomething" --> [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"My", @"Name", @"Of, @"Something"].`

I would like to do this without using a third-party regex library, since I will not need regex functionality for anything else in the program.

**UPDATE:**  I'm targeting older versions than iOS5/Lion, so no NSRegularExpression.  I know this can be done with NSScanner, but I was hoping somebody had a ready-made solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know this can be done with NSScanner, but I was hoping somebody had a ready-made solution.

Here you go:

```
    NSString *chopString = stringToSplit.copy; /// @"stringToSplit" Goes Here
    NSString *resultingString;

    NSCharacterSet *capsSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"];

    while (chopString.length > 0) {

        /// Pull the first character out each time ///
        /// Since it may trigger the Scanner ///
        NSString *firstChar = [chopString stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:(NSRange){1, chopString.length-1} withString:@""];
        chopString = [chopString stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:(NSRange){0,1} withString:@""];

        /// Scan up to the next Capital letter ///
        NSString *upToString;
        NSScanner *chopScanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString: chopString];
        [chopScanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:capsSet intoString:&upToString];

        /// Feed first character and scan results into string ///
        /// Separated by a space ///
        if (!resultingString)
            resultingString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",firstChar,upToString];
        else
            resultingString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@%@", resultingString,firstChar,upToString];

        /// Chop the remaining string down by the length of the scan ///
        chopString = [chopString stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:(NSRange){0,chopScanner.scanLocation} withString:@""];
    }

    resultingString = [resultingString capitalizedString]; /// @"String To Split" Comes Out!
```

Comment: Just posting a piece of code may not help. Please give some explanation.

Comment: Added context.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on iOS5/Mac OSX 10.7 you can use NSRegularExpression to get the positions of capitalized letters. (and then use substringWithRange:) If you need backwards compatibility, NSScanner is your (inefficient) friend.

Comment: Alas, my deployment target is 10.5, so no NSRegularExpression.  NSScanner is the obvious choice, but I was hoping to save myself the trouble of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: @KevinBallard well NSScanner itself is not inefficient, but the code you have to write is quite a lot. More code usually means that you aren't very efficient.

Comment: @ThomasBartelmess: Less code may just mean that you're relying on a lot of code behind the scenes. Regular expressions aren't usually known for being the fastest way to implement parsing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression to do this. Use http://rubular.com to test your Regular Expressions, and RegexKitLite (http://regexkit.sourceforge.net/RegexKitLite/) to add Regex functionnality to your application.

Here's a regular expression that should do the trick (it selects all capitals in the NSString): `[A-Z]`

I'm not sure, but I think you can take advantage of this method `- (NSArray *)componentsSeparatedByRegex:(NSString *)regex options:(RKLRegexOptions)options range:(NSRange)range error:(NSError **)error;` to do what you want.

The advantage of this is it works on 10.5, and it's really simple to implement !